Wiring 8 workshop outlets to one light switch
I want to wire multiple outlets that are powered by a switch. The power is coming to the switch from the panel first. Then to the outlets. Would like to turn all of them on and off. Would prefer a diagram for the answer. And is it safe?
Switch is rated “16X / 250 ~”
(Europe)
Thank you!

I think it is done the same in Europe, but live to the switch and switch live to the first outlet, with neutrals connected in the switch box to the first outlet.  Then live to live, neutral to neutral to each other outlet in line.  It is safe as long as you do not try to pull too much power in the circuit.  Using eight motors bad, using seven lights and one motor, good.
